# c# Regex capture all matches

Tags: c#, regex, match

My input string is :

```
(article.dos = $_article.dos_2_998_$ or article.des like $_article.des_3_%toto tata_$)
```

My current regex is : `(.*)(?<t>\$_(.+)_\$)(.*)`

So I want extract all $_ ... _$, but regex.Matches gives only the last match : $_article.des_3_%toto tata_$

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

edit : The input string can also contains $ character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
(?<t>\$_([^$]+)_\$)
```